# Non-negative polynomials $f(p), p\in P$ from Polynomial ideal where $P$ compact polytope?

Tags: polynomials, convex-polytopes, real-algebraic-geometry, polytopes

*Partially related to [Non-negative Polynomials from Polynomial Ideal?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245080/non-negative-polynomials-from-polynomial-ideal) where focus on graph theory but now I want to understand more generally how to determine non-negativity in more general case.*

A. Let $P$ be the polytope where $p_i^{lowerBound}\leq p_i\leq p_i^{upperBound}$. How can you determine to which product of simplicial complexes $P$ is affinely equivalent?

> Example Answer. The polytope spanned by the each entry in probability vector is affinely equivalent to some polytope in cases such as product of 1-dimensional hypercubes in the case of $p^{lowerBound}\leq p_i\leq p^{upperBound}$ for all $i$.

B. If the polytope is not equivalent, how does the paper *In praise of order units Journal of Algebra and Its Applications* discusses this?

C. If Gröbner basis needed for determining the non-negativity, how to determine the Gröbner basis to do computations and which monomial ordering? Reverse lexicographic monomial ordering?

D. How are the positivity results used for finding non-negativity of polynomial?

**How can you find non-negative polynomials $f(p)$ from a polynomial ideal when $p\in P$ and $P$ is a compact polytope?**